# Include a PHP function in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, function, web, include, prestashop

I have a commercial site built using Prestashop 1.7. My boss asked me to add a function that gives a discount to a customer if her comes from another site.

I have found a tutorial that explains how to do this in PHP.

However, I can't manage to add PHP to Prestashop. I can't find where to add my code nor where to include it.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must generate "PrestaShop module" for this purpose.

<< note: Changing the PrestaShop codes is not recommended >>